# Fragment Display in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to display a fragment in a `ViewPager` and I would like to have a button to replace the fragment in the `ViewPager`. I have managed to set up using examplesIi found on stackoverflow. However, how can I toggle between the 2 fragmentA and FragmentB.

Thank you so much.

My code is as follows :

```
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos1;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager=fm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {

        if (object instanceof FragmentA && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof FragmentB)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        if (object instanceof FragmentB && mFragmentAtPos1 instanceof FragmentA)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        switch (position){

        case 1:
            if (mFragmentAtPos1 == null)
            {

                mFragmentAtPos1 = FragmentB.newInstance(new FirstPageFragmentListener()
                {
                    public void onSwitchToNextFragment()
                    {
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos1).commit();
                        mFragmentAtPos1 = new FragmentA();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        showToast("in switchtoNextFragmentA ------------1");
                    }
                });

            }
            return mFragmentAtPos1;

        case 0:
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null)
            {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = FragmentA.newInstance(new FirstPageFragmentListener()
                {
                    public void onSwitchToNextFragment()
                    {
                        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0).commit();
                        mFragmentAtPos0 = new FragmentB();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        showToast("in switchtoNextFragment");
                    }
                });
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;


        default: return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}



public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
Button button;
static FragmentB b;
static FirstPageFragmentListener fpl1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, group, false);
}

public static Fragment newInstance(FirstPageFragmentListener firstPageFragmentListener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fpl1 = firstPageFragmentListener;

    if (b == null)
        b = new FragmentB();
    return b;

}


public static FragmentB newInstance() {
    if (b == null)
        b = new FragmentB();
    return b;
  }
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fpl1.onSwitchToNextFragment();

        }
    });
  }
}
```

UPDATE : layout file

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lbltime"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" 
    android:id="@+id/framelayout">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFCC" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: so you want to navigate from One Fragment to Another fragment By Pressing a Button am i right??

Comment: Hi Rickkky , yes i want to navigate from to/fro fragment through the press of a button.

Comment: Hi I have updated my layout file in my qns after doing as your suggestion . Both my fragment are now showing . Did i miss a step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple just do this

inside your button onClick method

```
Fragment f;
        f = new FragmentTwo();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentSupportManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_details_fragment_container, f);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Hi , I received the following error when i try to do so .

`04-30 05:57:01.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 05:57:01.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7647): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08000e (com.i2r.myreader:id/layoutb) for fragment FragmentB{40dcc9d8 #0 id=0x7f08000e}
04-30 05:57:01.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7647):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
04-30 05:57:01.079: E/AndroidRuntime(7647):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)`

Comment: have a putted your view pager in a FrameLayout are you using  that Framelayout Id in   ft.replace(R.id.main_details_fragment_container, f); if not please put it in a Framelayout.

Comment: Hi I have updated my layout file in my qns after doing as your suggestion . Both my fragment are now showing . Did i miss a step ?

Comment: Both fragment are now showing at the same time instead of 1 replacing another.